# Merge two dataframes based on some similar columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am guessing the answer is out there but my googling is not finding it.

I have two dataframes (eventually will have a bunch) that I want to merge together. Eventually this dataframe should grow into something with many rows and columns.

```
df1

Init Date   2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 06:00:00 2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-01 18:00:00
2021-01-01  37.3                35.29               35.72               41.28   

df2
Init Date   2021-01-01 06:00:00 2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-01 18:00:00 2021-01-02 00:00:00
2021-01-01 06:00:00 35.35       35.54               41.12               42.33
```

The general structure is this: each dataframe has an `Init Date`, which are sequentially ordered every 6 hours. Each column after `Init Date` represents a time in which there is a value, which also are sequentially ordered every 6 hours. The trick is that as you increase the `Init Date` time, so also does the first hour of data. As such, when we get the desired output we would expect that the second row, first column that is not `Init Date` to have no data, and so on down the line (third row would have first two columns empty). I tried several `pd.merge()` and `pd.concat()` options but could not find the correct one.

Expected output would be:

```
df3
Init Date   2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 06:00:00 2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-01 18:00:00 2021-01-02 00:00:00
2021-01-01  37.3                35.29               35.72               41.28
2021-01-01 06:00:00             35.35               35.54               41.12               42.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df, df2])
```

```
    Init Date   2021-01-01 00:00:00     2021-01-01 06:00:00     2021-01-01 12:00:00     2021-01-01 18:00:00     2021-01-02 00:00:00
0   2021-01-01             37.3                       35.29                   35.72                   41.28                NaN
0   2021-01-01 06:00:00     NaN                       35.35                   35.54                   41.12              42.33
```

Comment: concat seemed to worked for me, why not for you? I'm missing something?

Comment: When I do this it sets the first 4 columns as NaNs (second row) and then adds the data to 4 new columns. The first row then has 4 new columns at the end that are NaNs.

Comment: that happens when the column names are not the same. can you check that? Result is from the data  you shared in the question

Comment: Ah, seems I had that issue. Weird! Thanks.